# Inserting information from Netbeans IDE into Microsoft Access Database

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have a project that has to be handed in that I'm struggling to complete. I need to insert information into a Microsoft Access Database. I have managed to connect to the database with UCanAccess, but my Insert query does not seem to work. Here is one of my methods where I try to insert a shirt to my database (please excuse the Afrikaans)

```
   public void InsertHemp2(){

     try {

         String inNuweBeskrywing = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe sal u die kledingstuk beskryf?"
                + " Bv Slaaphemp");
        int inVlakVanDeftigheid = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Op 'n skaal van 1 tot 10,"
                + " hoe deftig sal u die kledingstuk beskryf? Bv 'n pak is 'n 10"));
        String inKleur = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wat is die kleur van die kledingstuk?");

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Neil\\Documents\\Skool\\Neil\\Matriek\\IT PAT\\Neil\\TrekRegAan '15 Code\\TrekRegAan_(3)\\TrekRegAan\\TrekRegAan'15\\TrekRegAan'15.accdb");
        st = conn.createStatement();
      st = conn.createStatement();
      String sql = ("INSERT INTO tblHemde (Beskrywing, VlakVanDeftigheid, Kleur)"
                + " SELECT " + "'" + inNuweBeskrywing + "'" + " AS Expr1" + "," + "'" + inVlakVanDeftigheid + "'"
                + " AS Expr2"  + "," + "'" + inKleur + "'" + " AS Expr3" + ";");
      st.executeQuery(sql);




     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

}

When I copy String sql and run it in access as a query, the records are inserted, so I doubt the fault lies with my query. I get the following errors:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: ;
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: ;
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:202)
    at Klasse.Hemp.InsertHemp2(Hemp.java:105)
    at GUI.GUI.jButtonVoegKlereByActionPerformed(GUI.java:148)
    at GUI.GUI.access$000(GUI.java:21)
    at GUI.GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:92)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ;
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:199)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ;
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSelect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source`enter code here`)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Does it help if you remove the semicolon from the string you generate?  (Given your error message, that's the first thing I would try.)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your error. It appears that UCanAccess does not like that form of an "INSERT ... SELECT ..." (with no FROM). However, you really should not be using dynamic SQL to construct statements like that because it leaves your application open to *SQL Injection* vulnerabilities and other nuisances.

Instead, you should be using a *parameterized query* like this:

```java
String sql = 
        "INSERT INTO tblHemde (Beskrywing, VlakVanDeftigheid, Kleur) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, inNuweBeskrywing);
    ps.setInt(2, inVlakVanDeftigheid);
    ps.setString(3, inKleur);
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```